# Visual Studio Debugging - Symbols never load, causing program freezes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

*On Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012 Professional, if it's relevant.

I've been stuck on this issue for several days now and scoured all remotely related stackoverflow answers I can find with no solutions working. The project developers seem to have no idea and I don't think it's related to their code but rather my setup.

I'm attempting to debug a C++ application written by someone else, same code runs without issues on several other computers but freezes on my computer when opening a windows file dialog (for opening or saving files.)

Per the debugger it'll freeze while trying to load symbols from libraries such as:

- shdocvw.dll (most common)
- networkexplorer.dll
- ieframe.dll
- dfscli.dll
- wbemsvc.dll
- FirewallAPI.dll
- npmproxy.dll

and a number of others. I've let it sit over night and once if freezes it never seems to recover.

I've essentially tried all the possible configurations in Options->Debug->Symbols, including enabling and disabling the Microsoft Symbol Servers, explicitly giving it the location where these libraries should be located, project directories, loading all modules or only specified modules, clearing the cache, excluding the libraries that cause freezes (they still load+freeze,) etc

Note that deleting all breakpoints, a common solution to these types of problems, has no effect.

It will very randomly work perfectly but then restarting the program, while changing literally nothing, will make the problems come back. It's rather infuriating. The most reliable method I've found is to let it load all symbols from the Microsoft Symbol Servers for one to three runs, and then once that stops working clear the cache and run it completely locally one time, then go back to the Microsoft Symbol Servers. Though that's not a very good solution and odd that it works.

Any ideas for an actual solution?

Comment: I suspect you're rather confused. The _program_ doesn't load the symbols, Visual Studio does. And Visual Studio loads those symbols asynchronously. The fact that your program freezes is unrelated.

Comment: Possibly, I've never seen this kind of issue before, but the symbol loading does seem to highly correlate to the program freezing. When the program works without issues all the symbols load 1-10+ per second, otherwise it all freezes at the same time.

Comment: @MSalters If the VS debugger is attached to a process, that process will "freeze" while VS loads symbols. Triggering something like an open file dialog can cause a bunch of new DLLs to be loaded into the process and by default VS will try to get symbols for them all.

Comment: @MKennedy Do you get different/better results if you start the program normally and then attach the debugger once it's up and running?

Comment: Whenever a thread deadlocks then it will of course also stop loading DLLs. Deadlock bugs rarely repeat well and are often affected by timing.  So you are focusing on the completely wrong issue.  UI thread deadlocks are a fairly common mishap whenever you open a file dialog, programmers have too many shell extensions installed on their machine and they are not exactly always of the best quality.  Use SysInternals' AutoRuns to disable them.